# changing a quick launch icon with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am new to vbscript. I am trying to change my quick launch icons via vbscript. One of these icons is for whatever game I am currently into and changes often. my question is how I can set the icon without knowing what the shortcut name will be. Would it be possible to search for all shortcuts in the folder excluding the ones that wont change and then use the remaining shortcut to set the parameters of the "set objFolderItem()" statement for the game shortcut. My current code.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
usrname = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\Users\" + usrname + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("foobar2000.lnk")
Set objShortcut = objFolderItem.GetLink
objShortcut.SetIconLocation "D:\Arthur\Graphics\Icons\Quicklaunch\Ico\Music.ico", 0
objShortcut.Save

Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Game.lnk")
Set objShortcut = objFolderItem.GetLink
objShortcut.SetIconLocation "D:\Arthur\Graphics\Icons\Quicklaunch\Ico\Game.ico", 0
objShortcut.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
RefreshMenu Method

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Description

Refreshes the contents of the Start Menu.


Syntax
object.RefreshMenu



Parameter Description 
object  Required. An object expression that evaluates to a Shell object. 


See Also
Shell
```

Else kill and restart explorer.exe.